# Jest is not calling function correct number of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am mapping over an array and then calling an external function. example

```
['error1', 'error2'].map(err => myFunc())
```

then in my jest test I am saying, expect `myFunc()` to have been called 2 times
but it's saying it is only called once

it's an external function defined as such

```
export const myFunc = () => {}
```

then when I import im doing

```
import { myFunc } from 'file/path'

jest.mock('file/path', () => ({
    myFunc: jest.fn(),
}))

expect(myFunc.mock.calls).toHaveLength(2)
```

anyone see what I'm doing wrong? really makes no sense as function should be called for every item in array :/

Comment: Where's the array in the test?

Comment: I'm just testing the array in the original code?

Comment: It’s a hard coded array with 2 entries?

Comment: oh no sorry I am mocking it with an array of 2 errors. and when I log it out, it's showing the array of length 2. but for some reason it's only showing one function even though the function should be called for every item in the array. so when I change to length 5, it's still only being called once :/

Comment: Hmm the issue is not obvious to me unfortunately. A live example on jsfiddle or similar might help.

Comment: @FrankModica happy to do a jsfiddle or something similar but not sure how I would get it working as all reduxy and would have to paste a hell of a lot of code in there? but I could draft up a concept if that helps?

Comment: Try to find the minimum amount of code that reproduces the issue